# Cannot load Plot package in Julia

Tags: julia

I am using Julia on a Mac laptop. Everything worked fine until yesterday when I want to do some plots I can no longer import the **Plots** package. When I try to do **Using Plots**, I receive the following error message:

[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching floatrange(::Type{Float64}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
floatrange(::Type{T}, ::Integer, ::Integer, ::Integer, ::Integer) where T at twiceprecision.jl:381
floatrange(::AbstractFloat, ::AbstractFloat, ::Real, ::AbstractFloat) at twiceprecision.jl:395
Stacktrace:
[1] floatrange(a::Float64, st::Float64, len::Float64, divisor::Float64)
@ Base ./twiceprecision.jl:403
...

**What I have tried**: I have tried the following methods but unfortunately none of them works:

1. Tried to do Pkg.update(), Pkg.resolve(), Pkg.gc()
2. Tried to first do Pkg.rm("Plots") and then Pkg.add("Plots"). Both commands executed without errors but when I try to import the package again the same error message occurs.
3. Tried https://juliapackages.com/p/pkgcleanup but it doesn't work.
4. Tried all methods mentioned in these two links:
   https://discourse.julialang.org/t/methoderror-no-method-matching-floatrange-when-running-histogram-1-7-0-win-11-21h2-amd-5900hx/72679/6
   https://discourse.julialang.org/t/methoderror-no-method-matching-floatrange-when-running-histogram-1-7-0-win-11-21h2-amd-5900hx/72679/6
   but unfortunately nothing worked.

The links above did mention something about deleting "old manefest/project files" but unfortunately, as someone who is new to Julia, I have no idea what this means, or how to do that. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what other packages you have in your environment? `]status` in the REPL should return the list. `versioninfo()` output might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @SundarR for helping me. The issue has now been resolved, which is a version issue. I asked the same question here and obtained a solution: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/cannot-load-plot-package-in-julia/98244

Answer (score 1):

> Your plots is pretty outdated - the current version is 1.38.11. Do add Plots@1.38 in the Pkg REPL to see what’s holding it back.
>
> On a related note, it is not recommended to install all packages in the default environment. You should keep only development dependencies like IJulia, Revise etc. in the default environment and work in project specific environments with only those packages needed for a specific piece of work to minimise these kinds of version conflicts. ([Source](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/cannot-load-plot-package-in-julia/98244/8))

[Note for future readers: the current version of Plots.jl will most likely change over time. You can find the most recent version [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl).